# how to get jquery onClick event on elements when they contain eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div that contains a table

```
<div id="container">
<table id="data">
<tbody>
......
......
</table>
</div>
```

i have bindind the onclick event on table rows so that if the user clicks a row, it is highlighted

```
$("#data tr").mouseup(function() {

        $("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");// Deselect currently selected rows
        $(this).addClass("selected");       
        });
```

now if the user clicks somewhere outside the table, i want to deselect the row. the problem is if i bind the click event with the div, both the table and the div gets the callback...how can i only get a callback for the div? so that i can deselect the rows!! i even tried binding the onClick with the body element but it luks like if u bind an event with an element, all the elements inside it will get the callback. if thats the case how can i deselect the rows then if user clicks outside the bounds of table.

Comment: In regards to "all the elements inside it will get the callback", they don't actually get the callback but the event does bubble up the hierarchy (up to the document object) and along the way triggers the callback of the container element. That's why stopPropagation is needed as Semyazas pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the bubbling of nested elements. You can stop that by using

```
$("div").click(function(e) {


            if($(this).attr('id')=="data")
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                return;
            }


                $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

        });

        $("#data tr").mouseup(function() {


        $("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");// Deselect currently selected rows
        $(this).addClass("selected");       

        });
```

From: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation

Comment: Thanks alot Semyazas....dint know about stopPropagation(). it solved the problem. althought i dont hav to place the stopPropagation() in the table rows .mouseUp event. im editing ur answer so that anyone else in search can know the exact solution. hope u dont mind.